# issue with an older nodejs code import { resolve }

Tags: node.js

I have an older version of code written in 2017 using React.
Getting this error while running npm run start. Not to sure if it is node version related.

Using node v: 10.16.2

```
$ npm run start

> starter-kit-react@0.0.1 start C:\xampp\htdocs\react\tool-master
> webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080

C:\xampp\htdocs\react\tool-master\webpack.config.babel.js:4
import { resolve } from 'path';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at loader (C:\xampp\htdocs\react\tool-master\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\xampp\htdocs\react\tool-master\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at requireConfig (C:\xampp\htdocs\react\tool-master\node_modules\webpack\bin\convert-argv.js:96:18)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\react\tool-master\node_modules\webpack\bin\convert-argv.js:109:17
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! starter-kit-react@0.0.1 start: `webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the starter-kit-react@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-08T00_15_37_258Z-debug.log
```

I was able to go past this step after upgrading babel

[Babel Upgrade details here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-upgrade)

However, now I am stuck where code is showing the below error. Initially it showed the processing went well and then stuck at some syntax error. Not sure what it is.

```
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ContentProvider lang="en">
      <App />
    </ContentProvider>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Error shown below:

```
$ yarn start
yarn run v1.17.3
$ webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080
Project is running at http://0.0.0.0:8080/
webpack output is served from /
Hash: b06107c62fb824ae192d
Version: webpack 2.7.0
Time: 498ms
                               Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
      vendor.e33c4b5498769f380132.js     326 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  vendor
         app.955a9ae9e538a29c3be3.js    2.58 kB       1  [emitted]         app
    manifest.58eaa606281aa83df76a.js    6.07 kB       2  [emitted]         manifest
  vendor.e33c4b5498769f380132.js.map     387 kB       0  [emitted]         vendor
     app.955a9ae9e538a29c3be3.js.map  104 bytes       1  [emitted]         app
manifest.58eaa606281aa83df76a.js.map    6.17 kB       2  [emitted]         manifest
                          index.html  126 bytes          [emitted]
chunk    {0} vendor.e33c4b5498769f380132.js, vendor.e33c4b5498769f380132.js.map (vendor) 323 kB {2} [initial] [rendered]
    [3] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080 7.93 kB {0} [built]
    [4] ./~/ansi-html/index.js 4.26 kB {0} [built]
    [5] ./~/ansi-regex/index.js 135 bytes {0} [built]
    [6] ./~/html-entities/index.js 231 bytes {0} [built]
    [9] ./~/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js 7.86 kB {0} [built]
   [10] ./~/node-libs-browser/~/events/events.js 13.6 kB {0} [built]
   [11] ./~/node-libs-browser/~/punycode/punycode.js 14.7 kB {0} [built]
   [15] ./~/sockjs-client/dist/sockjs.js 181 kB {0} [built]
   [16] ./~/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {0} [built]
   [17] ./~/url/url.js 23.3 kB {0} [built]
   [18] ./~/url/util.js 314 bytes {0} [built]
   [19] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.67 kB {0} [built]
   [20] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.08 kB {0} [built]
   [22] (webpack)/hot nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 160 bytes {0} [built]
   [23] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 77 bytes {0} [built]
     + 8 hidden modules
chunk    {1} app.955a9ae9e538a29c3be3.js, app.955a9ae9e538a29c3be3.js.map (app) 2.34 kB {0} [initial] [rendered]
    [2] ./src/index.jsx 2.3 kB {1} [built] [failed] [1 error]
   [24] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080 ./src/index 40 bytes {1} [built]
chunk    {2} manifest.58eaa606281aa83df76a.js, manifest.58eaa606281aa83df76a.js.map (manifest) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]

ERROR in ./src/index.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:\xampp\htdocs\react\tool-master\src\index.jsx: Unexpected token (18:2)

  16 |
  17 | render(
> 18 |   <Provider store={store}>
     |   ^
  19 |     <ContentProvider lang="en">
  20 |       <App />
  21 |     </ContentProvider>
    at Parser.raise (C:\xampp\htdocs\react\tool-master\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:6325:17)
    at Parser.unexpected (C:\xampp\htdocs\react\tool-master\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:7642:16)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (C:\xampp\htdocs\react\tool-master\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:8841:20)
    at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (C:\xampp\htdocs\react\tool-master\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:8412:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (C:\xampp\htdocs\react\tool-master\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:8392:21)
    at Parser.parseExprOps (C:\xampp\htdocs\react\tool-master\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:8267:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (C:\xampp\htdocs\react\tool-master\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:8240:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (C:\xampp\htdocs\react\tool-master\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:8187:21)
    at Parser.parseExprListItem (C:\xampp\htdocs\react\tool-master\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:9491:18)
    at Parser.parseCallExpressionArguments (C:\xampp\htdocs\react\tool-master\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:8621:22)
    at Parser.parseSubscript (C:\xampp\htdocs\react\tool-master\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:8514:29)
    at Parser.parseSubscripts (C:\xampp\htdocs\react\tool-master\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:8433:19)
    at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (C:\xampp\htdocs\react\tool-master\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:8422:17)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (C:\xampp\htdocs\react\tool-master\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:8392:21)
    at Parser.parseExprOps (C:\xampp\htdocs\react\tool-master\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:8267:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (C:\xampp\htdocs\react\tool-master\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:8240:23)
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080 ./src/index
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
    chunk    {0} index.html 542 kB [entry] [rendered]
        [0] ./~/lodash/lodash.js 541 kB {0} [built]
        [1] ./~/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./~/html-webpack-plugin/default_index.ejs 538 bytes {0} [built]
        [2] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
        [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Comment: Did you try `var resolve = require { resolve } from 'path'` or `import resolve from 'path'`

Comment: Same unexpected token issue

Comment: Try this `npm install @babel/core @babel/register @babel/preset-env --save-dev` and remove the `{ }` from around resolve

Comment: Sorry it says 
$ npm run start

> starter-kit-react@0.0.1 start C:\xampp\htdocs\react\tool-master
> webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080

C:\xampp\htdocs\react\tool-master\webpack.config.babel.js:4
import resolve from 'path';
       ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Do you have babel core and babel/preset-env installed? If not install those and try

Comment: installed it like you mentioned, but same issue remains

Comment: Try running your node server like `node --experimental-modules  your_server_start_file.mjs` Make sure the extension is `.mjs`

Comment: I was able to go past that error however now stuck at another. I have updated the post above